# Convert word date in SAS to ddmmyy format

Tags: date, formatting, sas

I have a date and time character variable in SAS (example 01 September 2016 00:00:00 GMT) and I want to store the date part of this as a DDMMYY8. format. I'm not sure how to do this or if there's a quick way to do it without using INDEX to find the spaces and compress it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to INPUT it to a datetime?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use scan function to separate the date values and convert them to a date variable:

```
data test;
char_date='12 September 2016 00:00:00 GMT';
format date date9.;
date=input(scan(char_date,1," ")||substr(scan(char_date,2," "),1,3)||scan(char_date,3," "),date9.);
run;
```